# Full height image with text column on the side in Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want something really simple but I can't manage to get it right with Bootstrap (4.3.1). It looks exactly how I want it, but I know the css is not correct.

I want an image that covers the entire col-xs-4 column in both height and width and a position of fixed so that it stands still when you scroll the col-xs-8 content.

On mobile, I want the image to be col-12 and the col-xs-8 column as well (so basically stacked).

I can't seem to figure out the correct css for this.. as you can see in my snippet, the image has a hard width of 40% and if I make it 100%, it just ignores the Bootstrap columns and fills the entire screen..

```css
.bg-image {
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    border-right: 10px solid #f5f5f5;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bg-image-content {
background-image: url(https://www.marenklif.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/kabouter-rood.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 col-xs-12">
      <div class="bg-image">
        <div class="bg-image-content">
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-7 col-xs-12">

      jnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihv jnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihv
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fixed elements does not listen to it's parents, it will be stacked to window

Comment: Sorry mate, can't get it to work, no matter what I try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to body overflow hidden to prevent page scroll so you can fix the image usign 100vh and for the text create another div with overflow scroll.

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bg-image-content {
background-image: url(https://www.marenklif.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/kabouter-rood.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 col-xs-12">
      <div class="bg-image">
        <div class="bg-image-content">
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-7 col-xs-12">
      <div class="scroll">
      jnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihv jnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihv
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re using `col-xs-` — that’s from Bootstrap 3; it doesn’t do anything in Bootstrap 4. For small screens, use col-12, and then set your break to side-by-side columns using something like `col-md-5.` Using `position: fixed` as @Abhishek pointed out doesn’t pass along the height to its parent.

You want the text column to scroll, but you didn’t say how height the image column is. What sets the height, the viewport?

Here’s an example of what you could do with the height of the row set to the height of the viewport:

```css
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .bg-image {
        border-right: 10px solid #f5f5f5;
    }

    .overflow {
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid no-gutters">
    <div class="row vh-100">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-5 h-100 px-0">
            <div class="bg-image h-100">
                <img class="h-100 w-100" style="object-fit: cover;" src="https://www.marenklif.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/kabouter-rood.jpg" alt="Kabouter rood">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-7 h-100 px-0 overflow">
            <p>jnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihv jnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihvjnsjv uwhv ihvi vhfi viuhv fihv
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I do need the image to be a background image, not a regular image. Thanks again!